# Javascript update to asp:HiddenField isnot detected server side in IE, but works in Chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

We've got an ASP page with a hidden field on it.  This field stores a selected value for deletion from a DB:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TargetField" runat="server" />
```

The same page produces a popup which contains among other things, a delete button - clicking this button "sets" this field and triggers server code:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DataBoundGuidField") %>' />
```

Server code has already programatically set the "OnClick" JavaScript in the appropriate DataBound handler (this works):

```
var btnSelectValue = CType(e.Row.FindControl("SelectValue"), Button)
btnSelectValue .Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').value=document.getElementById('{1}').value; return true;", SourceField.ClientID, TargetField.ClientID))
```

Then the server code has a handler for the click:

```
protected void DeleteButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // this line is the problem - it is always string.Empty in IE9 but works in Chrome !?
    var selectedValue = TargetField.Value
}
```

I don't need to understand a way to re-write it right now, just to understand why this mechanism of copying the value to an element and reading it on the server works in Chrome but not IE9 ... and whether there is a fix.  Thx in advance.

**UPDATE**

On request, here are the top few lines of rendered HTML (there are no METAs):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><link href="..</head>
```

Here are the top few lines of ASPX markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/Menu.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="EditScreen_Default" title="Edit Screen" %>    
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" Runat="Server">    
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

And this is the SourceField.CliendId / TargetField.ClientId values rendered in HTML respectively:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$GridViewRows$ctl03$SourceField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_GridViewRows_ctl03_SourceField" value="8aaa7a7a-7082-4a1b-8dab-c25b0d98c263" />                  
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$TargetField" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_TargetField" />
```

Comment: Does the same behavior persist if you hardcode `onclientclick` event in the button's ASPX markup?

Comment: It can't be hardcoded into the ASPX markup since the values it needs are dynamic and based on row output from a table.  However, adding btnSelectValue.Attributes.Add("onclientclick" ... as per the code I showed does exactly the same thing, i.e. comes through on the server code unmodified.

Comment: No "onclientclick" can only be added to ASPX markup, it translates into "onclick" in the rendered button. But I didn't mean it as a permanent solution, just as a test to see if it works in this case.

Comment: Also, what do SourceField.ClientID and TargetField.ClientID look like and what "mode" is your IE9 running in (Doctype, EmulateIE) ?

Comment: Ok yes, so when I put it hardcoded to set it to a certain value in the ASPX markup for the button, the server side event shows the updated value ...

Comment: SourceField.ClientId = ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_GridViewRows_ctl02_SourceField, TargetField.ClientId = ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_TargetField ... hardcoding these ClientId's into an "onclientclick" javascript expression in the popup template works - but I don't know when these ClientId's won't be valid - is it after code changes or just randomly according to execution?

Comment: Can you verify what SourceField and TargetField actually look in rendered page HTML (and what their IDs look like) ? Also can u update your post with top few lines of the page ASPX markup (including DOCTYPE and all the METAs) ?

Comment: Ok, added as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the update, weird, everything look in order. Just to verify -in the same renderd page (in IE9) does "onclick" attribute looks correct and references correct IDs?

Comment: Rendered HTML shows "onclientclick" but ID's are correct.  Could it be the popup?  We have an ASP panel on the ASPX on which the button is defined to "confirm" delete and this is where hardcoded "onclientclick" worked fine.  However, if i put the hardcoded "onclientclick" into the other button reference (the first one, which brings up the popup) it doesn't work.  I.e. it changes the document element but then when the popup comes up, it has changed back or forgotten it ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two button approach.

Use the delete button you have now to call the JavaScript.

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("DataBoundGuidField","javascript:RunJavaScript({0});") %>' />
```

A secondary button will actually post the page back.

```
<asp:Button ID="HdnDeleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteButtonClickHandler" Style="display: none;" />
```

Use Javascript to set your hidden filed and click a hidden button to do server side processing

```
function RunJavaScript(id){   
     $('#<%=TargetField.ClientID %>').value = id;

     //Call the hidden delete button for server side
     $('#<%=HdnDeleteButton.ClientID %>').click();    
}
```